# ReacJS Axios patch request URL with state not working

Tags: json, reactjs, axios, patch

I am trying to use the axios patch request on the last element of my db.json.
For that I am setting the state of "id" to the length of the data from the json. If I console log my state it will give me the right number. But if I put the state to the URL nothing happens there. Using a normal number instead of a state is working. What am I doing wrong?

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    const sub = this.newsletter();
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/posts')
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({id: res.data.length});
                    console.log(this.state.id);

                    
                });
                if(sub){
                    axios.patch(`http://localhost:3001/posts/${this.state.id}`,{
                        newsletter: 'yes'
                    })
                                .then(res => {
                                  console.log(res);
                                  console.log(res.data);
                                })
                            }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

wait for the state to be updated by your id and then call the second patch request. because setting state takes some time.

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    const sub = this.newsletter();
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/posts')
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({id: res.data.length} , () => {
                    // NOW OUR STATE HAVE THE PROPER ID 
                    if(sub){
                      axios.patch(`http://localhost:3001/posts/${this.state.id}`,{
                        newsletter: 'yes'
                      })
                       .then(res => {
                              console.log(res);
                              console.log(res.data);
                            })
                         }
                       }  

                    });
                    
                });
```

Comment: Thanks so far! I understand where you come from. But the funny thing is, that if i would write axios.patch(`http://localhost:3001/posts/10) it will work. But if I use a let or var, doesn't matter if i write the value like: let id = 10 or let id = res.data.lenght. neither of it would work

Answer (score 0):

`setState` in not synchronous. You can think of it as `enqueueSettingTheState`. So when the first `then` block is completed we can't be sure the state is set or not yet.

What you can do is to just not store anything on the state and go ahead and call the `patch`:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
  const sub = this.newsletter();
  axios.get("http://localhost:3001/posts").then(res => {
    // Read the value you want
    let id = res.data.length;
    if (sub) {
      // Use the value without storing it
      return axios.patch(`http://localhost:3001/posts/${id}`, {
        newsletter: "yes"
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks so far! I understand where you come from. But the funny thing is, that if i would write axios.patch(`localhost:3001/posts/10) it will work. But if I use a let or var, doesn't matter if i write the value like: let id = 10 or let id = res.data.lenght. neither of it would work

Comment: @Undelivered, check the network tab of the devtool and see what url is being used. Any error in the console?

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/yQWc2Yk/Bildschirmfoto-2020-10-20-um-11-22-35.png This is what I get after clicking the submit button. I can't read anything out of that

Comment: @Undelivered, add a `.catch(console.error)` to the axios call and you probably see an error in the console.